# How can I access the value of ForeignKey inside the model definions?

Tags: python, django

I have Car model

```
class Automovil(Item_Inventario):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Acme')
    model = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Acme')

   price = models.FloatField(default=0.0)
```

And a Sales model

```
class Sale(models.Model):
    salesman = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    buyer = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    buyer_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True,
                                default='00000000')
    car = models.ForeignKey(settings.MODELO_AUTO)
    amount = models.FloatField(default=car.price)
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
```

And I would like to calculate amount with the price of the car in question, unfortunately I can't do car.price inside the model definition. So how can I accomplish this?

Comment: If you have a price in the Automovil class, why you need the same data in Sale ?

Comment: Since the default value should take an instance, it's impossible to set it the way you've done. To my mind @ozgur 's solution is what you are looking for, however, I really do not understand the reason why you need to store the same data twice in db.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't relate fields like that when defining a model. The easiest way would be  overriding [`Model.save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.save) method:

```
class Sale(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(settings.MODELO_AUTO)
    amount = models.FloatField()
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.amount = self.car.price
        super(Sale, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, althought to make it work I had to use cleaned_data

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to calculate `amount`, you can define a [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/signals/) to do this:

```
#models.py

from django.db.models.signals import pre_save

class Automovil()...

class Sale(models.Model):
    ...
    amount = models.FloatField()
    ...

def calculate_amount(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):

    instance.amount = instance.car.price

pre_save.connect(calculate_amount, sender=Sale)
```